# Python - checking for an ip address (and nothing after it)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a Python (2.7) function that will take a string and return true if its input is an ip address, possibly with a slash in the end, but false otherwise. 
It needs to return a false value if the string is not just an ip address, but an ip address followed by some sort of path.
It doesn't matter if the address is a valid IP or not (999.999.999.999 can be considered an ip address for that matter).

eg:
"124.131.141.248" - true
"124.131.141.248/" - true
"124.131.141.248/bla" - false
"hello world" - false

I've tried searching for a solution but most solutions include just checking for a valid IP address, disregarding my other needs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Or the new [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) might help.

Comment: use python regex

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be working:

```
import re
def valid_ip(ip):
    if re.match(r'(\d+\.?){4}\\?$', ip):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Why the `^` at the end of the regular expression?

Comment: My bad, `$` is right.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to solve using a simple regex:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}(\/)?$")
string1 = "124.131.141.248"
string2 = "124.131.141.248/"
string3 = "124.131.141.248/bla"
string4 = "hello world" 
print(pattern.match(string1)!=None) # true
print(pattern.match(string2)!=None) # true
print(pattern.match(string3)!=None) # false
print(pattern.match(string4)!=None) # false
```

[Here](https://repl.it/Grce/1) a running example.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work, I should've thought of it myself